# C# compare two strings for matching words

Tags: c#, string

I have two strings containing letters and numbers separated by spaces. ex 
"elza7ma wa2fa fel matab" and "2ana ba7eb el za7ma 2awy 2awy"

What is the fastest way to compare this two string to find out whether or not they have a word in common?

I tried to split one of them using string.split and use string.compare on the whole array of words. but this is very slow since I will be comparing a lot of strings.

Comment: it seems that indexOf will work faster then regex, however don't know if it is faster then string.compare :). You can try

Comment: Do you actually want *fastest*? You could work for literally *years* on that problem. I suspect that you want *fast enough*, in which case, you haven't given enough information to solve the problem. *What is your hardware, what is your time budget, and what is a typically-sized problem?*

Comment: Also, what is "a lot of strings"?  Your comments below indicate that "a lot" is hundreds. I would consider hundreds to be an *incredibly tiny number of strings*. Is that accurate? I would consider "a lot" to be millions or billions of strings - as in, Bing indexes a lot of strings. Without having a good idea of the size of the problem it is difficult to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 15):

A LINQ solution

```
"elza7ma wa2fa fel matab".Split()
                         .Intersect("2ana ba7eb el za7ma 2awy 2awy".Split())
                         .Any();

// as a string extension method
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool OneWordMatches(this string theString, string otherString)
    {
        return theString.Split().Intersect(otherString.Split()).Any();
    }
}

// returns true
"elza7ma wa2fa fel matab 2ana".OneWordMatches("2ana ba7eb el za7ma 2awy 2awy");
```

Comment: No overload of `Split` takes a single `char`.  Probably best to also specify `RemoveEmptyEntries`

Comment: You can use the `Split()` without any parameters. In this case it will use spaces, tabs and new lines as separator.

Comment: Is this really faster, or does Intersect() also loops through both arrays?

Comment: Not sure about performance, will need to benchmark them. I suspect a hashset implementation like JaredPar's would be faster

Comment: This one is implementation is excellent. I will be comparing hundreds of strings so performance is a must. Do you know whether this is faster or the hashset? how can I know?

Comment: @Marwan: You can know by *trying it both ways and measuring the results*. How else could you possibly know?

Comment: @Russ: FYI Intersect already uses a Set<T> class internally to implement intersection.

Comment: @Eric - Thanks - I couldn't quite see what was going on in Reflector :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way is to break up the strings into words and use a set structure like `HashSet<string>` to check for duplicates.  For example

```
public bool HasMatchingWord(string left, string right) { 
  var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(
    left.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)); 
  return right
    .Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Any(x => hashSet.Contains(x));
}
```

Comment: Might want to add an equality check as well to handle collisions (if there are any).

Answer (score 1):

You could split the two strings by word and build two hashtables/dictionaries. Then go through both and add keys incrementing an int in a third dictionary (`Dictionary<string, int>`). If any key in the third dictionary have a count of more than one, that word is in both original strings.

I would think that any algorithm to solve this problem would be 'slow' - especially for large input strings/many words.

Comment: Adding all words to the same HashSet and checking the return value of Add() is simpler.

Comment: I re-read the original question - yes it would be much simpler. He is just asking if there are any words that are represented in both strings - not which and not how many occurences.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably take the initial performance hit and split the string and then order alphabetically and by word length.
If you just have to find out if one word matches, break as soon as you find one.
Once you have the split string arrays ordered alphabetically and by length, that limits the numbers of compares you would have to do.

Answer (score 0):

- The easiest way would be to compare all words to any other word. This is an easy solution, but slow.
- Another way is to sort both lists, and then compare the top two entries. Like mergesort, but with the goal of finding equal words.
- Another way is to compile the list of words into a tree, and match the words against that tree. A regex can do this, or you can do this yourself. In your example, the first letter should be 2, b, e or z. This way, each word is only inspected once and the least number of characters are inspected.